# Swift 4, error, UITableViewController perfrom segue, Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

See code below.
I would like to preface this by saying I am new to swift and xcode.

I am attempting to create a segue using this code snippet here:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        if(indexPath.row == 3) {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "warehouse", sender: self)
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT on the below AppDelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
        guard let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController,
            let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
            let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterVC,

            let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailVC
            else { fatalError() }

        let firstMail = masterViewController.mail.first
        detailViewController.mails = firstMail
        masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController
        masterViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
        UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .blue
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .automatic
        splitViewController.delegate = self

        return true
    }


    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController: UIViewController, onto primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else {return false}
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailVC else {return false}
        if topAsDetailController.detailMail == nil {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

I have searched for this error code and it appears to be related to code either missing or incorrect code. And since I am new to swift I cannot figure out what I am missing. 
Below here is the entire code snippet for the tableView I wish to perform a segue from to a new view controller

```
import UIKit

class SideMenuTable: UITableViewController {


    var menu = [Menu]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Change Menu View"

        menu = [
            Menu(title: "Main"),
            Menu(title: "Departments"),
            Menu(title: "Deliveries"),
            Menu(title: "Warehouse"),
            Menu(title: "Help")
        ]


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if tableView.isHidden {
            if let selectionIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPath, animated: animated)
            }
        } else if tableView.isFocused {
            if let selectionIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                tableView.deselectRow(at: selectionIndexPaths, animated: animated)
            }
        }
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 5
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sideCell", for: indexPath)
        let menuSide: Menu

        menuSide = menu[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel!.text = menuSide.title
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center

        return cell
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Warehouse" {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Warehouse", sender: self)
            }
        }
```

EDIT----

Sorry here are the logs I forgot to show.

```
2018-07-20 12:23:38.509524-0400 WFMailRoom2[18281:778852] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-gFD-aE-X8s" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5411e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001098d6031 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a5b6975 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000010ae610e0 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 629
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ab61d21 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 175
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010aba920c -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 68
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010aba94ea -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 136
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010abaa61e -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 870
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010abab86c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 150
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ae03d0b -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 231
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010aa8d7a8 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1515
    11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111e10456 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 177
    12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111e14667 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111d9b0fb _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 343
    14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000111dc879c _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 568
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a9e6f2c _afterCACommitHandler + 272
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4e3607 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4e355e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4c7b81 __CFRunLoopRun + 1537
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a4c730b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001116aea73 GSEventRunModal + 62
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010a9be057 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  WFMailRoom2                         0x0000000108e6feb7 main + 55
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ee71955 start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: "I have searched for this error code " You didn't gave the logs, that's important. Show what are the messages in Console/Debugguer when it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear:

> instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-gFD-aE-X8s" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.

So there is something wrong with the configuration of this view controller in the storyboard. It is supposed to be a UITableViewController, but apparently it is not, or else — and this is most likely — you have accidentally unhooked the View outlet that runs from the view controller to the table view and hooked it to something else.

Comment: The message is clear, however I cannot figure out where I went wrong.. I do not recall 'unhooking' anything

Comment: Of course you don't recall it. You don't do it on purpose. Anyway you don't need to recall anything: just look right at the connections inspector for the view controller in the storyboard and see! Don't speculate, for heaven's sake. It's trivially easy to see what's wrong and fix it.

Comment: I meant to say that there are no missing or incorrect connections as far as I can see. And again, as I am still new I may not be seeing the missing connection 
thanks for the responses

Comment: I cannot guide your hands, but if you want to post the project on github or similar, I'll attempt to fix it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Simply this recursive calling

```
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "Warehouse", sender: self)
```

in prepareForSegue here

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Warehouse" {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Warehouse", sender: self)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!  Unfortunately I may have made a mistake uploading incorrect code. However I have tried your suggestion in replace of the code snippet i used and i receive this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee6c54ff8)

Comment: comment this line inside **prepare**  , and try

Comment: sorry still get error: SIGABRT: LOGS:  "UIViewController-gFD-aE-X8s" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView.

Comment: may be you mistakenly deleted the table in IB

Comment: I cannot figure for the life of me where this missing "table" went... 
Thanks for the assistance SH_Khan